# Node: prototype using "Class" syntax does not show expected object

Tags: javascript, prototype, es6-class

In JS, if I use a constructor function to create a new object, and I access the prototype object I'm able to see any property the prototype has. (in code which will much more clear):

```
function F() {
  this.attr = 42;
} 
F.prototype.foo = function() {
  return 'life';
}

$> let f = new F();
undefined
$> f
F { attr: 42 }
$> Object.getPrototypeOf(f)
F { foo: [Function] }
```

Right here everything is OK.

Now, I'm going to use the *class* syntax in order to create the same scenario

```
class C {
  constructor() {
    this.attr = 42;
  }
  foo() {
    return 'life';
  }
}

$> let c = new C()
undefined
$> c
C { attr: 42 }
$> Object.getPrototypeOf(o)
C {}
```

That resulting `C {}` is confusing me. **Where is my `foo` attribute?** it's not in the `c` object, but seems to be neither in my `C` prototype!

Comment: I just ran your code in Chrome Dev Tools and I'm seeing `foo` after I expand the object. You can also prove that `foo` exists on that object by doing `Object.getPrototypeOf(o).foo`. Your environment just isn't displaying it immediately.

Comment: @MikeC My env is the node console

Comment: So Node just doesn't display all of the elements on the prototype when showing a class specific prototype. The property still exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably, the issue is that your console does not include non-enumerable properties when displaying an object.

In your first case, you create the properties by assignment, so they are enumerable:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(F.prototype, 'foo').enumerable; // true
```

But in the second case they are not

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(C.prototype, 'foo').enumerable; // false
```

That's why you should never trust object representations in console. If you want to list all the own properties of an object, this will probably work:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(C.prototype); // [ "constructor", "foo" ]
```

You may want to join that array if your console is not able to properly display arrays neither.